# I'm having trouble visualizing the solution to this double integral of an ellipse

Tags: integration

I've been given this question:
for $\displaystyle
  D = \left\lbrace \; (x,y) \; \left|
          \frac{ ( x - 3 )^2 }{ 9 }
        + \frac{ ( y + 4 )^2 }{ 16 }
        \leq 1
      \right.\right\rbrace$
 Find: 
$\displaystyle
   \iint_{D}
     \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{ ( x - 3 )^2 }{ 9 }
              - \frac{ ( y + 4 )^2 }{ 16 }
          }
     \; dx dy$ 
So in order to find it the excersize suggests we transform our cartesian coordinates into polar ones centered at (3,-4)
$\displaystyle
   \left\lbrace
     \begin{array}{lcr}
        x & = & 3 +  3 r \cos\theta \\
        y & = & -4 +  4 r \sin\theta
     \end{array}
   \right.$

 Now I understand what happens here mathematically (and have had no trouble finding the jacobian and doing the transformation) but I don't really get what we're doing here visually - and how do I derive the new integral limits of $r$ and $\theta$, or what it is we're actually calculating in the first step. Basically - what does the calculation "look like" visually before and after the transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before that change of variable, the region over which you are integrating is the ellipse $D$. But$$(x,y)\in D\iff x=3+3r\cos\theta\wedge y=-4+4r\sin\theta\text{ for some $(\theta,r)\in[0,2\pi]\times[0,1]$},$$and therefore after the change of variables the region over which you will be integrating is the rectangle $[0,2\pi]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: but why is theta defined at [0,2pi] and r at [0,1]? is this something I just have to accept or memorize? what's the rationale here?

Comment: The values of $\theta$ go from $0$ to $2\pi$ (or any other interval with length $2\pi$) because there are points of the ellipse all around $(3,-4)$. If, say, you were interested only on the top half of the ellipse, $\theta$ would go from $0$ to $\pi$. And $r$ goes from $0$ to $1$ because, if $x=3+3r\cos\theta$ and $y=-4+4r\sin\theta$, then$$\frac{(x-3)^2}9+\frac{(x+4)^2}{16}\leqslant1\iff r^2\leqslant1\iff r\in[0,1]$$(since $r\geqslant0$).

Comment: I see, thank you!